# Validation and Test Evaluations in TensorFlow Demos

Tags: tensorflow

The [TensorFlow beginner demo](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners) code includes files `mnist_softmax.py` and `fully_connected_feed.py`. My understanding is that the beginner demo is based on running `mnist_softmax.py` while the expert demo is based on running `fully_connected_feed.py`.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding above correct?
2. If the above is correct, then is it also true that the
   beginner code (`mnist_softmax.py`) does *not* use validation data
   to stop training, and instead simply runs until the max number of
   epochs (1000 in the demo code)? `fully_connected_feed.py` evaluates against validation data
   but I have not found where the beginner code (`mnist_softmax.py`) does.
3. The beginner demo should be run by executing `mnist_softmax.py` and `fully_connected_feed.py` is meant for use only in the [TensorFlow Mechanics 101 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own anwer: Yes, the code runs to a max number of steps, and `fully_connected_feed.py` is for the later demos.

Comment: You are allowed to [accept](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) your own answer.